# changing validation of input value based on list-box value

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery validation plugin ( http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ )

I have following structure:

```
<select name="s1" id="s1">
   <option value="url">url</option>
   <option value="normal">normal</option>
</select>
<input name="s1_value" id="s1_value" type="text" />
```

Now, I need validation rule (using jQuery validation plugin) as

If I select 'url' as value in list box, then input field should only contain valid URL

If I select 'normal' as value in list box, then input field can contain any text

For any selection, value for input field should not be empty

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation plugin allows rules to be specified in each element's class. You can start with the `required` and `url` rules:

```
<input name="s1_value" id="s1_value" type="text" class="required url" />
```

From there, you can remove the `url` class if the list box value becomes `normal`:

```
$("#s1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "url") {
        $("#s1_value").addClass("url");
    } else {
        $("#s1_value").removeClass("url");
    }
});
```

That way, the validation plugin won't validate the field against the `url` rule, since it does not expose that rule in its class.

You can test this solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yhYy5/).

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the simpliest solution could be just using the http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules rules("add",rules) function to add and rules("remove",rules) to remove rules depending on select value of that select.

```
$("select").change(function(){
  if(this.value == "url") {
    $("input").rules("add",{
      url: true
    })
  }
  if(this.value == "normal") {
    $("input").rules("remove", "url")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a `change` event to the select input:

```
jQuery("#s1").change(function(){
   var val = jQuery(this).val();
   ...
});
```

Then within that function, use the [`add` and `remove` functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) from the validation plugin to adjust your rules as necessary.